# Mac Pro upgrade options

Tags: macos, graphics-card, cpu, mac-pro

Currently I have two Mac Pro towers (3,1 and 5,1) with the following configurations and I am planning some upgrades (described below). I just want to double check if everything sounds right and reasonable.

Thanks in advance for any comments and advice. Much appreciated!

**Mac Pro 3,1**

- Xeon E5462 Quad 2.8GHz
- 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR2 800MHz FB memory
- 320GB HDD
- NVIDIA 8800 GT

*Upgrades*

- an extra E5462 on eBay with apple heatsink, thermal paste and then put it onto the empty CPU slot 2.
- 16 (8 x 2GB) FB memory. I'm planning to purchase the crucial memory but when I compare it with the original apple OEM RAM (visually) the ram by Crucial does not have heatsinks. Would it cause the RAM to fail prematurely?
- get an Samsung 850 EVO SSD
- upgrade graphics to GTX 570

**Mac Pro 5,1**

- 2 x Xeon X5670 Six-core 2.93GHz
- 52GB (6 x 8GB, 2 x 2GB) DDR3 1333MHz ECC
- 840 EVO SSD
- NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti

*Upgrades*

- The CPU should be fine, I lost of reference guide for memory slotting but I put my memory in the following configuration and wondering if it's correct: `{{8,8,8,8},{8,8,2,2}}` where `{Riser card A{Slot 1,2,3,4},B{1,2,3,4}}`
- I'm thinking about upgrading to a GTX 970 (after watching a youtube video, which shows it's somehow possible to put that in) but I don't know if I have enough power supply. Currently I have dedicated both power cables to power this 750 Ti (8pin-6pin, 6pin-6pin) and I'm not sure about 970.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the Mac Pro 3,1:**

The upgrades sound reasonable, however here's a few comments:

The extra CPU seems like it could be expensive for such an old part. Make sure the extra processing power is worth it to you.

I dont understand why you would replace the existing memory (you write that you currently have 2 x 4GB and want to upgrade to 8 x 2GB). Why not just get an extra 2 x 4GB instead of replacing the memory that's already in the machine. The benefit of filling all slots is very very minor ([source](http://eshop.macsales.com/Reviews/Framework.cfm?page=/Benchmarks/macproearly08ram/article.html)).

Replacing a spinning hard drive with an SSD is the best thing you can do for pretty much any computer these days, so that's definitely a good idea

I havent been able to find definite information about if the GTX 570 is actually compatible with the system. But someone in this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5037735?start=0&tstart=0) claims that:

> All nVidia GTX works perfect. No need special edition, all works in
>   10.8.2   I have the GTX 770 running in my Mac Pro 2008. In OSX and Windows (bootcamp)

**For the Mac Pro 5,1:**

The memory configuration is correct. You can't do it any better except by replacing your 2GB RAM modules with 8GB ones.

Again, I can't find any definitive information in the video card, so make sure it's compatible before you purchase.

Comment: Much thanks for the help! I might put the 750 Ti on my 2008 Mac Pro to reduce cost at the mean time keeping 8800 GT for booting purposes. Hopefully the PCIe port and the power cables have sufficient power supply for the 970 or 980.